# Firebase remote config returns an object

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-remote-config

Trying to get Firebase remote config working. A remote config parameter "ab_placeholder_value" has been setup with a default value "abvertisement" in Firebase, published too.

React Native code:

```
remoteConfig().fetchAndActivate()
      .then(fetchedRemotely => {
        if (fetchedRemotely) {
          console.log('Configs were retrieved from the backend and activated.')
        } else {
          console.log(
            'No configs were fetched from the backend, and the local configs were already activated',
          )
        }
      })
    remoteConfig().fetch(0)
    const val = remoteConfig().getValue('ab_placeholder_value')
    console.log('The ab_placeholder_value: ')
    console.log(val)
    
    remoteConfig().fetch(1)
    const all = remoteConfig().getAll()
    console.log('All values: ')
    console.log(all)
```

Output:

```
 LOG  The ab_placeholder_value:
 LOG  {"_source": "default", "_value": "disabled"}
 LOG  All values:
 LOG  {"ab_placeholder_value": {"_source": "default", "_value": "disabled"}}
 LOG  Configs were retrieved from the backend and activated.
```

Looks like the app is talking with the Firebase server, since the parameter name "ab_placeholder_value" has been retrieved.  But why is the parameter value an object: {"_source": "default", "_value": "disabled"}?
How can I get the value set in Firebase remote config? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

remoteConfig().fetchAndActivate() returns an object.  You can access values of it in your case by using **._value**:

```
 const val = remoteConfig().getValue('ab_placeholder_value')._value;
 console.log('The ab_placeholder_value: ')
 console.log(val)
```

I initially run everything through a function to create a remoteConfigValues object and then access values stored in that object throughout the code to make things a bit more readable:

```
remoteConfig.fetchAndActivate()
  .then(() => {
      remoteConfigAllObj = remoteConfig.getAll();
      var remoteConfigValues = {};
        
      for (let key in remoteConfigAllObj){
          remoteConfigValues[key] = remoteConfigAllObj[key]._value;
      }
    })
```

The values from the remoteConfig object then become available using the dot notation from the created remoteConfigValues object.

```
console.log(remoteConfigValues.ab_placeholder_value);
```

NOTE – In my case I load the remoteConfig before app initialization at startup.  The remoteConfigValues object will therefore contain whatever is activated at that time, so it may be a mix of values from static, remote, and default variables.  If you want to know where the values came from originally, you'll find that information under remoteConfigAllObj[key]._source for each key in the remoteConfigAllObj that you gathered in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same behaviour that boolean parameter that i created in firebase remote config returned as object and has to access it by `._value` but later i found a method to get it as boolean as stated below

```
const isMaintenance = remoteConfig().getValue('is_maintenance')

if (isMaintenance.asBoolean() === true) {
  // Show maintenance screen
}
```

Also you can make it short in one line

```
const isMaintenance = remoteConfig().getValue('is_maintenance').asBoolean()
```